# Left join on null values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am facing the conceptual issue with the join in MYSQL

lets consider two table

```
Employee                        Salary
name      salary           Salary    Grade
Nikhil    10000            10000     A
Akhil     10000            20000     B
Shubham   NULL             10000     C
Abhishek  2000
```

and the sql query is

```
select *
from Employee as e LEFT JOIN
     SALARY as s
     on s.Salary = e.salary
```

in the output I am getting 6 rows instead of 4 rows.

```
name      salary   Salary    Grade
Nikhil    10000    10000     A
Akhil     10000    10000     C  
Nikhil    10000    10000     C   
Akhil     10000    10000     A      
Shubham   NULL     NULL      NULL
Abhishek  2000     20000     B
```

Comment: What do you imagine would happen, and why?

Comment: @Strawberry I was expecting four rows only, because during the left join we get all the rows from the left table and only intersection from the right table. number of rows should not be greater then the left table.

Comment: So would it return A or C? Surely you can see that your thinking is flawed!

Comment: @Strawberry lets say if I have another row in Salary table with sal = 10000 and grade = C,  then will I get 8 rows or 6 rows(I think I should get 8 rows)? and how can I delete the duplicate rows?

Comment: The situation cannot arise. A relational table in sql must have a unique key, otherwise it's not really a table. In your case, the unique key would be formed on the grade column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll assume that your sample data set should have `Abhisek  20000`, not `Abhisek 2000`, because you don't get the results you're puzzling over if you use `Abhisek 2000`.

Second, the use of `*` is returning duplicate columns.  (Yes, I know that one is called `salary` and the other is called `Salary` - but you're JOINing on that column.  They're the same value.  No need to return that value twice.)

Third, you don't seem to understand how a `JOIN` builds its results.  And the "extra" rows you're seeing come from the fact that *you're not JOINing on unique data*.  There are **2** rows in `Salary` that have a value of `10000` in the `Salary` column.

So your `LEFT JOIN` starts from the `Salary` table and tries to find a match in the `Employee` table *for every record in the Salary column*.  This is how the rows get built from the `JOIN`:

1. It looks for any records where `Salary.Salary = 10000 AND Employee.salary = 10000`.  (This is the `JOIN` for "Grade A".)  It finds 2 matches - one for Nikhil and one for Akhil. So you get 2 rows from this `JOIN`.
2. It looks for any records where `Salary.Salary = 20000 AND Employee.salary = 20000`.  (This is the `JOIN` for "Grade B".)  It finds 1 match (assuming that Abhisek's "real" value is 20000, and not 2000.)  So you get 1 row from this `JOIN`.  You now have 3 rows.
3. It looks for any records where `Salary.Salary = 10000 AND Employee.salary = 10000`.  (This is the `JOIN` for "Grade C".)  It finds 2 matches - one for Nikhil and one for Akhil. So you get 2 rows from this `JOIN`.  You now have 5 rows.
4. Finally, you end up with 1 more row for Shubham.  Shubham didn't match anything in the `JOIN`, but it was part of the original `SELECT ... FROM` clause.  So you still get that row returned.  You now have 6 rows.

Finally, it was suggested by another respondent that you can eliminate the `NULL` result by doing this:  `WHERE grade <> NULL`.  That's wrong.  That will eliminate **all** the rows.  If you want to filter out the `NULL` values, you would need to add this: `WHERE grade IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the correct answer.  There are two rows with `salary = 10000` in `Salary`.  Both those rows match Nikhil and Akhil resulting in duplicates.

This would happen with an `inner join`.  This would happen with no `NULL` values.

Presumably, the `salary` for `C` should be changed to something else.

Comment: so basically if I have 2 or more rows with same values then it will return all the possible cases?

Comment: @NikhilGupta . . . It will return all combinations of rows from the two tables where the join keys match.

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct. LEFT JOIN returns all records from the left table, even if there is no match in the right table (filling the fields with NULLs instead). 
The remaining rows in your result come from the repetition of the 10000 salary.

Answer (score 0):

Left join means all records in the left table, whenever it's not in right table. As your left table has null, it has 6 answers if you want 4 answers you can have a condition like this to omit nulls:
select *

from Employee as e left JOIN

SALARY as s

on s.Salary = e.salary where grade is not NULL
[image]